# G++ Unclear compilation failure

Tags: c++, gcc, compilation, makefile, g++

Good day everyone. This is my first question on stackoverflow. I googled and binged this thing to death but not one single hit. I am trying to compile a c++ lib with g++ on Mint 17. I am getting a frustrating unclear failure message. I would like to know if anyone has encountered this before. I realise it looks like a missing include, the strange thing is the location pointed out as the point of failure and the lack of information. Usually the compiler specifies which file it cannot locate. Please see the message below. Any suggestions will be greatly appreciated.

```
"/usr/bin/make" -f nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk QMAKE= SUBPROJECTS= .build-conf
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/bfvanrooyen/Projects/Management Console/Event Monitor'
cd ../Perlingo\ Library && /usr/bin/make  -f Makefile CONF=Debug
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/bfvanrooyen/Projects/Management Console/Perlingo Library'
"/usr/bin/make" -f nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk QMAKE= SUBPROJECTS= .build-conf
make[3]: Entering directory `/home/bfvanrooyen/Projects/Management Console/Perlingo Library'
"/usr/bin/make"  -f nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk dist/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86/libbham_dev.so
make[4]: Entering directory `/home/bfvanrooyen/Projects/Management Console/Perlingo Library'
mkdir -p build/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86/src
rm -f "build/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86/src/BhamEvent.o.d"
g++ -m32   -c -g -Wall -Iinclude -Isrc -I../Perlingo\ Shared\ Objects -include include -fPIC  -MMD -MP -MF "build/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86/src/BhamEvent.o.d" -o build/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86/src/BhamEvent.o src/BhamEvent.cpp
In file included from <command-line>:0:0:
/usr/include/stdc-predef.h:59:1: fatal error: include: No such file or directory
 #endif
 ^
compilation terminated.
```

Comment: `-include include` what it supposed to mean? It is command to gcc to include file named 'include'.

Comment: @keltar, sorry, yes, include is a folder to include.

Comment: @bfvanrooyen then it should be `-Iinclude`. This is exactly what your error message says - compiler can't include file 'include', which you asked it to.

Comment: Thanks @keltar, you fixed my problem. It is a Netbeans generated make file. I'm going to read up on g++ and the toolchain. Thank you for helping.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your option `-include include` tells `g++` to include a *file* called "include". Said file can't be found according to `g++` and hence the error. Are you sure `-include include` is not just a copy & paste error of some sort?

When in doubt what all those flags and arguments do, you can find a comprehensive list in the `gcc` documentation [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Option-Summary.html).

Comment: That was the problem, mine was pointing to a folder. Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

I created a very similar error using NetBeans to build with g++.  In the project properties, I needed to share a directory of header files in ../Shared_files.  However, I accidentally put ../Shared_files in the property "Include Headers" instead of "Include Directories"